# How to levitate a SCNNode over another?

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit

I am trying to make a SCNNode float over a plane and then drop it.

To make it float:

```
floatingNode.position.z += 0.4 // It's rotated π/2 over x axis
planeNode.addChildNode(floatingNode)
sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(planeNode)
```

I know this is not actually floating, I just change its position.

To make it drop:

```
floatingNode.physicsBody.angularVelocityFactor = SCNVector3(0, 0, 0)
floatingNode.physicsBody.angularVelocityFactor.physicsBody.restitution = 0
floatingNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody.init(type: .dynamic, shape: SCNPhysicsShape.init(node: modelNode, options: nil))
```

But it doesn't drop to the very bottom, there is an space between the floatingNode and the plane. To fix this, after dropping I have to do:

```
floatingNode.physicsBody = nil
floatingNode.position.z -= 0.4
```

I need to set the physicsBody to nil, because I want to make it float again later.

Is there a way to make a SCNNode float over another without changing its position manually?

Comment: Did you check the physics shape of the planeNode? Does it has a thickness.

Comment: It's a plane:

planeNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .kinematic, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(node: SCNNode(geometry: SCNPlane(width: 100, height: 100)), options: nil))

Comment: It' not because of the thickness, It's because of that 0.4 Z increment.

Comment: what is the force to make it drop? Where’s the 0.4 from

Comment: I just want the SCNNode over the plane, so I increment its position over the Z axis a bit (0,4)

Comment: So you manually drop it. Not use physics world simulation